# How can i update a parse user account with different user account

Tags: javascript, parse-server

Hi i am trying do a very simple backend where admin can modify other users account but its not working. I understand this is happening because parse has some default security settings that does not allow this. Below is the code snippet from the update route of the web app:

```
//UPDATE ROUTE
router.put("/:id", function(req, res){
var Users = Parse.Object.extend("User");
var query = new Parse.Query(Users);

// find and update the correct user
query.get(req.params.id).then(function(user) {
      user.set("name", req.body.name);
      user.save().then(function(doctor) {
            console.log("user has been updated");
            res.redirect("/doctors/"+ req.params.id);
        }, function(error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        });
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("user could not be retrieved!");
    });  
   });
```

The Error Message is : Cannot modify user HeFxUOj7q9. HeFxUOj7q9 is the Objectid for the user which i am trying to update from another account(admin account)

I have an admin account already created on the parse server User class but I can't figure out how to update other accounts using the admin account. I am using parse server on nodeJs. I would really appreciate any help offered. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is this "backend" you are talking about? Can you provide some codes wich makes these errors?

Comment: very sorry i realized that i did not post a snippet of the code. I have just updated the post. Any help or ideas would go a long way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're initializing parse, you should include the `masterKey` and call `useMasterKey` like so:

```
Parse.initialize("YOUR_APP_ID", "YOUR_JAVASCRIPT_KEY", "YOUR_MASTERKEY");
Parse.serverURL = 'http://YOUR_PARSE_SERVER:1337/parse';
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```

However, be wary of doing this for endpoints that are publicly accessible, and never include your master key on a client-side application.

Comment: Oh great. This finally worked, I made the mistake of placing the masterkey in as the second parameter. Works great now. Thanks a million bro!

Comment: @felix Also if you have the masterkey, you can leave the javascript key blank like this (if you want to) `Parse.initialize("YOUR_APP_ID", "", "YOUR_MASTERKEY");`